# image fixed, but disappears behind div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The effect I'm looking for can be seen here, where the fixed_header_middle disappears behind the fixed_header_bottom.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).bind("scroll", function(e) {
    if (!$('#fixed_header_bottom').hasClass('fixed')) {
      if ($(document).scrollTop() >= 100) {
        $('#fixed_placeholder').show();
        $('#fixed_header_bottom').addClass('fixed');
      }
    } else {
      if ($(document).scrollTop() < 100) {
        $('#fixed_placeholder').hide();
        $('#fixed_header_bottom').removeClass('fixed');
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#fixed_header_top {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #DD33DD;
  top: 0;
}
#fixed_header_middle {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #DDDD00;
  top: 50px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: -1;
}
#fixed_header_bottom,
#fixed_placeholder {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #11DD55;
}
#fixed_header_bottom {
  margin-top: 150px;
}
#fixed_placeholder {
  display: none;
}
.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50px;
  margin-top: 0!important;
}
#body_block {
  background: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="fixed_header_top">fixed_header_top</div>
<div id="fixed_header_middle">fixed_header_middle</div>
<div id="fixed_header_bottom">fixed_header_bottom</div>
<div id="fixed_placeholder">Shouldn't see me</div>
<div id="body_block">BEGIN
  <br />
  <br />Bottom
  <br />Bottom
  <br />Bottom
  <br />Bottom
  <br />Bottom
  <br />Bottom
  <br />Bottom
  <br />Bottom
  <br />Bottom
  <br />Bottom
  <br />Bottom
  <br />Bottom
  <br />Bottom
  <br />Bottom
  <br />Bottom
  <br />Bottom
  <br />Bottom
  <br />Bottom
  <br />Bottom
  <br />Bottom
  <br />Bottom
  <br />Bottom
  <br />Bottom
  <br />Bottom
  <br />Bottom
  <br />Bottom
  <br />Bottom
  <br />Bottom
  <br />Bottom
  <br />Bottom
  <br />Bottom
  <br />Bottom
  <br />Bottom
  <br />Bottom
  <br />Bottom
  <br />
  <br />END</div>
```

In this example, however, there are other effects, such as the 
fixed_header_bottom becoming fixed.

I'm only interested in knowing how to make a fixed element disappear behind another element when scrolling down.

Comment: you didnt add an example but I am guessing z-index in css might help

Comment: Sorry I'm new here on stackoverflow, so please bear with me :-) Can you see the link now?

Comment: Think you might be right with the z-index.. Gonna look into that. thanks!

Comment: change this z-index: -1; to some higher number instead of -1

Comment: One more question.. So the effect should work on a background image, which is implemented via css, so how do I add the z-index effect?

Answer (score 0):

If i get what you want, z-index is what you are looking for...
It controls the overlays of elements..
See code below

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).bind("scroll", function(e) {
    if (!$('#fixed_header_bottom').hasClass('fixed')) {
      if ($(document).scrollTop() >= 100) {
        $('#fixed_placeholder').show();
        $('#fixed_header_bottom').addClass('fixed');
      }
    } else {
      if ($(document).scrollTop() < 100) {
        $('#fixed_placeholder').hide();
        $('#fixed_header_bottom').removeClass('fixed');
$('#fixed_header_bottom').css('z-index', -1);
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#fixed_header_top {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #DD33DD;
  top: 0;
}
#fixed_header_middle {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #DDDD00;
  top: 50px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: -1;
}
#fixed_header_bottom,
#fixed_placeholder {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #11DD55;
}
#fixed_header_bottom {
  margin-top: 150px;
}
#fixed_placeholder {
  display: none;
}
.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50px;
  margin-top: 0!important;
}
#body_block {
  background: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="fixed_header_top">fixed_header_top</div>
<div id="fixed_header_middle">fixed_header_middle</div>
<div id="fixed_header_bottom">fixed_header_bottom</div>
<div id="fixed_placeholder">Shouldn't see me</div>
<div id="body_block">BEGIN
  <br />
  <br />Bottom
  <br />Bottom
  <br />Bottom
  <br />Bottom
  <br />Bottom
  <br />Bottom
  <br />Bottom
  <br />Bottom
  <br />Bottom
  <br />Bottom
  <br />Bottom
  <br />Bottom
  <br />Bottom
  <br />Bottom
  <br />Bottom
  <br />Bottom
  <br />Bottom
  <br />Bottom
  <br />Bottom
  <br />Bottom
  <br />Bottom
  <br />Bottom
  <br />Bottom
  <br />Bottom
  <br />Bottom
  <br />Bottom
  <br />Bottom
  <br />Bottom
  <br />Bottom
  <br />Bottom
  <br />Bottom
  <br />Bottom
  <br />Bottom
  <br />Bottom
  <br />Bottom
  <br />
  <br />END</div>
```

Comment: So I found this http://www.madebydaryl.co.uk/ That is how I want the background to work..

Comment: notice that it is not every element in his header that the effect works on.. "made by.." is not fixed..